# How to find element in already parsed HTML data

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

Here I have a very simple code to grab all the 'div' elements with the classname 'info_block'. I am wondering how would I go about finding another element with the classname 'price' from within 'info_block' and display it instead of the whole 'info_block' element.
**Main Goal**: Find the price in each element with classname 'info_block'. but do inside the **foreach**, because I may need to find other elements.

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('example.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$div1 = $xpath->query('//div[@class="info_block"]'); 
foreach ($div1 as $var1){
//echo $dom->saveHTML($var1); 
}
?>
```

There is a element in each of the 'info_block' with a classname 'price' and I would like to display only that element. Like so...

```
   foreach ($div1 as $var1){ 
          $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
          $dom2->loadHTML($dom->saveHTML($var1));
          $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2); 
          $div2 = $xpath2->query('//div[@class="price"]'); 
          $div2 = $div2->item(0);
    echo $dom2->saveHTML($div2);
   }
```

But instead of just giving me the price it returns the whole HTML for 'info_block' as it did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide each `<div class="info_block">` found and search for `<div class="price">"` by providing it in the second argument of `->query()`:

```
$div1 = $xpath->query('//div[@class="info_block"]'); 
foreach ($div1 as $var1){ 
    $div2 = $xpath->query('./div[@class="price"]', $var1); 
                                             //     ^ each div
    $div2 = $div2->item(0);
    echo $dom->saveHTML($div2);
}
```

Note: You do not need to create another instance of `DOM` and `DOMXpath`.

This example is taken into context of this kind of HTML semantic:

```
<div class="info_block"> // each info block
    <div class="price">1</div> // inside of it has price
</div>
<div class="info_block">
    <div class="price">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: or why not just use `//div[@class="info_block"]/div[@class="price"]`, saves you the hassle

Comment: Having re-read the question properly I think this is the better solution

Comment: Ah I see there is no need to create a second DOM, Thank You!! Although the code looks great it makes the whole page load instead of just the HTML i'm looking for.

Comment: @RamRaider probably, maybe the OP needs do to something other than to directly point to the needed element

Comment: @StevenHammons what does _the whole page load_ mean?

Comment: Sorry my mistake on the page loading, but it does show the same price over and over because   $div2 = $div2->item(0); would only show the first price.

Comment: @StevenHammons you should have added at least a sample HTML in the question, most likely there is still HTML inside `<div class="price">`, you'll need to add more specific rule inside the second xpath query

Comment: @Ghost The HTML you provided is identical the problem is that it shows the same price over and over because your selecting the first price and showing it with each 'info_block' do I need another foreach statement ?

Comment: @Ghost Yeah I see your example is perfect, not sure why it's retrieving same price over and over. Hmmmm.

Comment: Thank You Everyone, I found the problem instead of ./div[@class="price" like @Ghost insisted I used //div[@class="price" .! Thank you all so much for helping me resolve this! I deeply appreciate it !

Comment: How would I grab the results if the page loads the data as you scroll....

Comment: @StevenHammons if this is loaded via javascript, you can't scrape it this way

Answer (score 1):

You can combine queries in XPath to find all the desired elements in one go

```
$xpath->query('//div[@class="info_block"]|//div[@class="price"]');
```

Comment: Say I had another element in there, '//div[@class="info_block"]|//div[@class="price"//div[@class="product"]'  price and product, echo $dom->saveHTML($var1(2)) << that would show product ?

Comment: I think Ghost's answer, esp the comment, is easier and more direct

Comment: to find the product directly you could do `'//div[@class="info_block"]//div[@class="product"]'`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify dom elements for doing relative XPath queries. Its optional in `xpath->query` method

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('example.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$div1 = $xpath->query('//div[@class="info_block"]'); 
foreach ($div1 as $var1){
  $div2 = $xpath2->query('//a[@class="price"]', $var1); 
  foreach ($div2 as $var2) {
    echo $var2->nodeValue. "\n";
  } 
}
?>
```

For more you can see xpath documentation here 
[xpath query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)